# Categorical variables in pipeline: dimension mismatch

Tags: python, pipeline, categorical-data, dictvectorizer

I try to build a pipeline with categorical variables

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(6),  'c':['a', 'b', 'c']*2, 'd': ['m', 'f']*3        })
X = df[['c', 'd']]
y = df['a']

regressor = linear_model.SGDRegressor()
```

Transform categorical variables

```
class Cat(TransformerMixin):

    def transform(self, X, **transform_params):
        enc = DictVectorizer(sparse = False)
        enc_data = enc.fit_transform(X.T.to_dict().values())
        return enc_data

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self
```

Pipeline

```
 pipeline = Pipeline([ 

                ('categorical', Cat()),
    ('model_fitting', regressor),
])
pipeline.fit(X, y)
```

That's correct. But i get error when i try to fit a new dataset. For example

```
contr = pd.DataFrame({'c':['a'], 'd': ['m']})
pred = pipeline.predict(contr)
pred
and

ValueError: shapes (1,2) and (5,) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)
```

Isee that the problem in class Cat(TransformerMixin). How to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

I've done as below. It works

I have altered function

```
class Cat(TransformerMixin):

def transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
    enc = DictVectorizer(sparse = False)
    encc = enc.fit(df[['c', 'd']].T.to_dict().values())
    enc_data = encc.transform(X.T.to_dict().values())
    return enc_data

def fit_transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
    self.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    return self.transform(X)

def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
    return self
```

And a new dataset

```
control = pd.DataFrame({'c':['b'], 'd': ['f']})
pred = pipeline.predict(control)
pred
```